# How can I add core data to a utility application

Tags: ios, core-data, utility

Ive made a simple ios utility application in xcode (version 4.4.1) but Ive realised that I need to store one integer in persistent memory. As far as I know using core data is the best way to achieve this.
Ive added the core data framework to my app but I dont know the code that I need to add for it to work.

Could someone please help

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this guide by Apple? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to store/retrieve an integer, `NSUserDefaults` should be the way to go.

**Saving**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];
```

**Retrieving**

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

Reference:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/